# Display div on img mouseover (jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, hover, mouseover

So I'm working on a mouseover effect on images that will display a div of text. I have the css all set but I'm having trouble with the Jquery. I'm using this inline in a wordpress theme, I'm wondering if that could be my problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".imgHover").hover(function() {
        $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.25)
        .end().children(".hover").show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1)
        .end().children(".hover").hide();
    });
</script>

<div class="imgHover">
    <div class="hover">Test Content for the hover</div>
    <img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" alt="" />
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code in [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".imgHover").hover(function() {
        $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.25).end()
            .children(".hover").show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end()
            .children(".hover").hide();
    });
});
```

or use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".imgHover",function() {
    $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 0.25).end()
            .children(".hover").show();
}).on("mouseleave",".imgHover", function() {
    $(this).children("img").fadeTo(200, 1).end()
            .children(".hover").hide();
});
```

Comment: Incidentally, you can replace `.end().children(".hover")` with `siblings(".hover")` throughout the code.